# android 2.3.5 phonegap app href not working

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-build

I have compiled my app using Phonegap build and successfully running the app on android 4.4.3, but when installed on an old 2.3.5 phone although the app runs it does not work on the href elements.
I am using handlebars templates and the area of code with the problem is...

```
<script id="campaign-li-tpl" type="text/x-handlebars-template"> 
    {{#.}}
    <li><a href="#cam/{{this.id}}">{{this.name}}</a></li>
    {{/.}} 
</script>
```

When the user selects an item from the list the location hash is changed which fires the event to display the appropriate page.

```
 $(window).on('hashchange', $.proxy(this.route, this));
```

On android 4.4.3 and also in the browser all is fine. On the 2.3.5 phone, the items respond to touch as I change the background with CSS, but nothing happens.

I compile using phonegap 3.7.0 with min sdk version of 10.

```
 <preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.7.0" />
 <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="10" />
```

Is there a known issue with older version of android?
Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: The WebView in Android is packaged (and not updated ever again) with the SDK, this means you are locked to the web compatibilities of that time period. In recent times Google has split the webview from the SDK and it is now OTA updateable (which is great) but for older devices you need to look up the compatibilities for the webview at that version.

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not work. Also, this is buried in the documentation, but in the [Android Platform Guide](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.2.0/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide) for Phonegap 3.2.0,  you will find - under **Requirements and Support**

> Cordova supports Android 2.2, 2.3, and 4.x. As a general rule,
>   platforms are deprecated as they dip below 5% on Google's distribution
>   dashboard.

Under [3.6.0](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.6.0/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide) (there is no 3.7.0 docs - as of this moment) it says:

> Cordova supports Android 2.3.x (Gingerbread, starting with Android API
>   level 10) and 4.x.

**SO, CHANGE**

```
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.7.0" />
```

**TO**

```
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.2.0" />
```

You may also want to set your `android-targetSdkVersion`

Comment: Thank you for the answer although it did not help. I re-compiled with Phonegap 3.2.0 and targetVersion set to 10 and it behaves exactly the same as before.

Comment: Okay. You'll need to go to the [Official forum](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi) I suspect that Phonegap only supports 2.3.x and up -- any more.